# Google Sheets different Right click menu between 2 accounts

Tags: google-sheets

Please look at the 2 photos. It's the same  Google Sheets file viewed on two different accounts. I need on the left account /photo to be like on the right side.
left=  work email.. created same way
right= personal email created same way..

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Are both accounts a `@gmail.com` account?

Comment: No, 1 is made with a adress that i already own at work so company email and 1 is with @ gmail.com.

The one with @gmail (photo right side 2) its good and the one with  @ MyCompanyEmail its not ok(photo left 1)

But there are coleagues who created accounts the same way, google accounts with microsoft adress to "TIE" it to outlook and for them its all good.. in the only one out of 40 employees

Comment: Is there something specific you are trying to make? If so, what is it?

Comment: There is no specific im trying to make, we use google sheets at work and we work on it.. but as you can see in a blank project, the right click its different between them.. and with the left side right click photo.. i have trouble doing Insert/Delete since its SHIFTING cells as well.

Comment: In the right menu, when you go to `Insert cells` it appears a submenu asking where to shift it, so it's actually the same. Did you meant insert a column or a row?

Comment: I want the left side photo account to have exactly like the right side photo...
on the left side account I cannot insert 1 row.. it will also SHIFT... i don't want to shift.. only to insert rows//column//delete.

Comment: I don't have this menu... could you take a screenshot of the `View more cell actions` submenu?

Comment: Sure, please check the edited post. i posted a photo from the right  click menu of the left side account.. the one with problem.

Comment: Thank you! Let me suggest something: select a cell and navigate to the bar menu `Insert > Add row above` (not on the right click). Does it modify the spreadsheet the way you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it does works good, that way. from Insert--Row-- Insert 1 above. But it only works from Insert--Row--Insert 1 row above/bellow.  while on the right click i dont have insert row i have insert Cells..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Answer (score 0):

For documentation purposes I'm adding a small explanation as an answer.

Google doesn't change UI for all the accounts at the exact same time, so that why you have different UIs.

In this case they removed option to insert a row from the right click menu, but it's still available in the menu bar (`Insert > Row > Insert 1 above`).

If you'd like to ask Google to revert the change, you can use the `Help > Help Sheets improve` and explain what happens (if makes you less efficient, I would state so).

Comment: Thank you, will do that.